# iproxy and paramiko give connection error

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I am attempting to use paramiko with iproxy to ssh to an iOS host, after Catalina seemingly killed my other method.

Firstly I forward local port to device port

`iproxy 2222 22 -u <UUIDxxxxxx>`

This can be seen on netstat that its listening

```
tcp6       0      0  ::1.2222               *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.2222         *.*                    LISTEN
```

However with paramiko, I always get a NoValidConnections error

`File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 368, in connect raise NoValidConnectionsError(errors)`

`paramiko.ssh_exception.NoValidConnectionsError: [Errno None] Unable to connect to port 2222 on 127.0.0.1`

Current python code is:

```
sshIP = "127.0.0.1"
sshPort = 2222

ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=sshIP,username='root',password=sshPass,port=sshPort)

stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh_client.exec_command("sw_vers")
prodver = stdout.readlines()
```

SSHing manually from cli works fine.

```
####IPROXY OUTPUT
New connection for 2222->22, fd = 5
waiting for connection
Requesting connecion to USB device handle 571 (serial: UUIDXXXXX), port 22

# CLI SSH
$ ssh root@127.0.0.1 -p 2222
Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:2222' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
root@127.0.0.1's password: 
Last login: Tue May 25 11:41:30 2021 from 127.0.0.1
iPhone-Black:~ root#
```

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure what was the overall fix, but I added a `time.sleep(3)` after calling iproxy to ensure that it had started successfully before calling paramiko.

I also changed the order of the paramiko options, and added port= after hostname= as per paramiko documentation.

`connect(hostname, port=port, username=None, password=None,`

Both of these seem to have helped and connections are now made correctly.

```
ssh_client =paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=sshIP,port=sshPort,username='root',password=sshPass)
```

Comment: The order of the parameters has no effect.